# How to create my own input for Python linked list questions?

Tags: python, linked-list

I have just started learning Python through LeetCode. I am in question 876 "Middle of the Linked List". The solution is as below:

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode(object):
#     def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.next = next
class Solution(object):
    def middleNode(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: ListNode
        """
        slow = fast = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        return slow
```

From LeetCode, when input is [1,2,3,4,5], output is [3,4,5]. May I ask how to create my own input when I am running this code in my own IDE? I tried the following

```
head = ListNode([1,2,3,4,5])
print(Solution().middleNode(head))
```

But it does not show me the correct output [3,4,5], instead, it shows "Process finished with exit code 0"

Thank you very much!

Comment: Leetcode usually has some kind of "driver code" to run the solutions. It might loop over the linked list or do other operations to properly format the output returned by your method. If you just want to test with custom testcases, they have a tab for that, you don't need to run it locally

Comment: 1. When you do `ListNode([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`, you created _one_ node with the value `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. 2. You do not specify how to convert a `ListNode` object to a string, so `print()` will simply print its memory location. E.g. running your code, I get the output `<__main__.ListNode at 0x215667719d0>`

Answer (score 1):

LeetCode lets you specify a linked list using Python list notation for convenience, since you can execute custom unit tests in the browser. The function doesn't *actually* take in a linked list; if you're running stuff locally, you have to convert from a vanilla Python list to a linked list.

The conversion you've done isn't quite right: what you've done is created a new ListNode that has its `val` field set to the list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, and its `next` field set to None.

Here's what you're looking for (iterating over each element in the input list, and inserting them into a linked list):

```py
def convert_to_linked_list(input_list):
    head = None
    for i in range(len(input_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        new_head = ListNode(input_list[i], head)
        head = new_head
    return head
```

Edit: To print out the values in the linked list (as asked in a follow-up):

```py
ll = convert_to_linked_list([1, 2, 3, 4])
current = ll
while current is not None:
   print(current.val)
   current = current.next
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried this convert_to_linked_list function by printing print(convert_to_linked_list([1,2,3,4])),  the result is <__main__.ListNode object at 0x7fe1c76a2820>, rather the the linkedlist 1,2,3,4. May I ask if there is anything I understood wrong?

Comment: That's expected, because the `__str__` method isn't overriden for ListNodes -- calling `print()` on a ListNode will output its memory address. Perhaps you were looking for `print(convert_to_linked_list([1,2,3,4]).val)` (which will print the head of the linked list)?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! May I ask what I should do to print everything in this linked list created (1, 2, 3, 4)?

Comment: Added to the original answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need two functions:

1. One to turn a standard list into a linked list (for calling the `middleNode`)
2. One to turn a linked list back into a list (for printing the result)

I would suggest to add methods to the `ListNode` class. The second one could actually be `__iter__` so that a linked list becomes iterable, and then you just have to put the `*` operator in your print statement:

```
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    @classmethod
    def of(Cls, lst):
        head = None
        for val in reversed(lst):
            head = Cls(val, head)
        return head

    def __iter__(self):
        head = self
        while head:
            yield head.val
            head = head.next

class Solution(object):
    def middleNode(self, head):
        slow = fast = head
        while fast and fast.next:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
        return slow


head = ListNode.of([1,2,3,4,5])
print(*Solution().middleNode(head))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm running this code on my end it looks like it is producing an output:

```
<__main__.ListNode object at 0x000001DCF7B5EFD0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It just doesn't seem to be the output that you're expecting. When I debug the code it seems that middleNode skips over the while loop, because by default the ListNode class next is None which is evaluated to false in python. So it's just returning slow, which is the original ListNode.